# Import Network Settings (wi-fi) from Windows to Mac; Bulk Import of Wifi Keychain Passwords

Tags: macos, mac, passwords, csv, keychain

I have a CSV/TXT file with a list of network names and passwords (together with network/password/encryption types) that looks like this:

```
  ***Networkname1***    ESS WPAPSK  TKIP    passPhrase  ***password1***
  ***Networkname2***    ESS WPAPSK  TKIP    passPhrase  ***password2***
  ***Networkname3***    ESS open    WEP     networkKey  ***password3***
  etc etc
```

I am trying to import the wi-fi network settings (for wireless hotspots) to the Mac's Keychain app as I have just moved from a Windows 7 machine to a Mac (Yosemite).

Any ideas? Perhaps I can edit the Keychain file that keeps the list of network names and passwords?

Perhaps there is a way to edit a Keychain file that contains all the wifi passwords.

Comment: The migrate ought to have brought them over.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to write a script to read your csv and parse it properly to one of the following terminal commands:

---

Apple has a [KB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html) of the `security` command (keychain access manager).

You'll need something like:

```
security add-generic-password -a $User -D "network password" -S $SSID -w $Password
```

Like -

```
security add-generic-password -a Raystafarian -D "network password" -S Raystafarian -w MyPassword
```

---

There's also the `networksetup` command [KB](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) to join a network -

```
networksetup setairportnetwork $device_name $SSID $Password
```

You can find which device name to use with

```
networksetup -listallhardwareports
```

You can also set preferred networks with **(This is what I would use)**

```
networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex $device_name $SSID $Index $Security_type $Password
```

Like -

```
networksetup -addprefferedwirelessnetworkatindex en1 Raystafarian 1 WPA2 MyPassword
```